# How to fix a SQL Server function that is used millions of times and regenerating in the query plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

I have a SQL Server function (see `fn_TestBinaryBitwiseOr` below) with millions of executions. While this is anticipated, SQL Server has an expensive query report that says:

> There have been multiple executions of this query pattern (query
> hash), but all of the executions are generating the same query plan
> (query plan hash).  This wastes CPU time to compile the query plans
> and memory to cache them.  To improve overall SQL Server performance,
> consider parameterizing this query (via the application, template plan
> guide, or forced parameterization). Refer to Books Online for more
> information on parameterization.

I am pretty sure I am hitting RedFlag #1 from https://eitanblumin.com/2022/08/25/too-many-plans-for-the-same-query-hash/ but still not sure what I can do in my case. I cannot use a stored procedure because it is used in another function in a select and has the output. I haven't gone to forced parameterization due to some of the downsides but may look into that next.

Is it possible to change `fn_TestBinaryBitwiseOr` below to a parameterized procedure? Is there a different solution to test.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION[dbo].[fn_TestBinaryBitwiseOr]
    (@TestFlags1 binary(16),
     @TestFlags2 binary(16))
RETURNS binary(16)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP(1) 
                          CASE
                              WHEN @TestFlags1 IS NULL AND @TestFlags2 IS NULL 
                                  THEN 0x0
                              WHEN @TestFlags1 IS NULL 
                                  THEN @TestFlags2
                              WHEN @TestFlags2 IS NULL 
                                  THEN @TestFlags1
                              ELSE
                                  CONVERT(binary(16), CONVERT(binary(4), (SUBSTRING(@TestFlags2, 1, 4) | CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(@TestFlags1, 1, 4)))) +  
                                                      CONVERT(binary(4), (SUBSTRING(@TestFlags2, 5, 4) | CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(@TestFlags1, 5, 4)))) +  
                                                      CONVERT(binary(4), (SUBSTRING(@TestFlags2, 9, 4) | CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(@TestFlags1,9,4)))) +
                                                      CONVERT(binary(4), (SUBSTRING(@TestFlags2, 13, 4) | CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(@TestFlags1, 13, 4)))) 
                )
            END
        )
END 
GO

-- another function to call my first function,
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION[dbo].[DoAThing]()
RETURNS @T TABLE(ColName binary(16)) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- sample data
    DECLARE  @Table1 TABLE (id int, binary1 binary(16))  
    DECLARE  @Table2 TABLE(table1Id int, binary2 binary(16))  

    INSERT INTO @Table1 
    VALUES (1, 0x10000000000000000000000000000A01), 
           (2, 0x00000000000000000000000000000101)

    INSERT INTO @Table2 
    VALUES (1, 0x00000000000000000000000000000100), 
           (2, 0x00000000000000000000000000000100)

    -- using a function from a function
    INSERT INTO @T(ColName) 
        (SELECT [dbo].[fn_TestBinaryBitwiseOr](t1.binary1, t2.binary2) AS result 
         FROM @Table1 t1 
         JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1Id)
    RETURN
END
GO

--executing
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[DoAThing]()
```

Comment: I can't see why both of those can't be an inline table-valued function which would likely be much more performant and also not be a black box in the execution plan.

Comment: You are correct. The second function is just made up. But the first one I did improve in that way. It will make it more performant but are you saying being less of a black box will allow it to parametrize? Going to make this change and test.

Comment: Certainly this type of scalar UDF can be horrible for performance but I'm not sure what the "Too Many Plans for the Same Query Hash" is about. The scalar UDF is already parameterised. You shouldn't need to do anything else on that.

Comment: That was my thought as well. this isn't a multi value table function its scalar. I still had variables defined in the function (before the edit) so I'm removing those to see if the DB can better utilize statistics.

Comment: fn_TestBinaryBitwiseOr seems like the sort of thing that SQLCLR would be _very good_ at.